# Rails validate three types of date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, customvalidator

i'm developing a Ruby on Rails application which uses a special kind of date format.
The date format in question is Year.month.day and a date can be:

Year.month.day
Year.month
Year

I'm working on a validation method that has to check the format and if the input date fits any of those formats, make it valid. So far my code is:

```
def data_format_correct
regexymd = /[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2}/
regexym = /[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}/
regexy = /[0-9]{4}/
if :data.to_s =~ regexymd
  return true
elsif  :data.to_s =~ regexym
  return true
elsif :data.to_s =~ regexy
  return true
else
  errors.add(:data)
  return
end
```

end

Everytime i put a date in the form, the else case rises with the error. I'm pretty sure my code is correct. Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

Found the solution. Works like this:

```
regexymd = /^[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2}$/
regexym = /^[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}$/
regexy =  /^[0-9]{4}$/
regex_final = Regexp.union(regexymd, regexym)
regex_final = Regexp.union(regex_final, regexy)

validates :data, :format => { :with => regex_final }
```

Hope that helps anyone in the same situation as mine. Thank you for the answers. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Can you past in the exception backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

You're not matching the variable `data`, you're matching the *symbol* `:data`, which is why it raises an error (it would be useful if you could post that error, btw).

Anyway I think what you want is something like this:

```
def data_format_correct
  regexymd = /[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]{1,2}/
  regexym = /[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{1,2}/
  regexy = /[0-9]{4}/
  if regexymd.match(data.to_s)
    return true
  elsif  regexym.match(data.to_s) 
    return true
  elsif regexy.match(data.to_s) 
    return true
  else
    errors.add(:data)
    return
  end
end
```

Comment: Figured it out! I join the three regexp in one using Regexp.join and then i pass the result to validates :data, :format => { with => result }. Did the trick. I'll post the solution. Thanks for the reply btw. I appreciate the feedback :-D